# How to populate UITableView with plist

Tags: uitableview, plist

I have a simple UITableView that I'd like to populate using a plist file. I have followed a few tutorials but they all seem to over complicate the process and in the end I end up getting errors or my app simply does not work.

I'm using a window based application.

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 3):

To load the file :

```m
thearray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
```

Then you need to set your controller as the data source and delegate for the table view and implement at least :

```m
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    return [thearray count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

    // assuming your array contains only simple strings :
    cell.textLabel.text = [thearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

This doesn't use the "reuse" of cells which is important if your list is big.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there a way to choose which fields I want to return. I have a `root` which is an array. inside that I have `item 0` which is a dictionary. and inside that dictionary I have things like name, location and so so on. How can I just return `name` from every item?

Comment: In the cellForRow... method you would write cell.textLabel.text = [[thearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

Comment: Also remember to do [self.tableView reload]; after loading the array