# Load data from plist to tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview, plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to populate UITableView with plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133812/how-to-populate-uitableview-with-plist)

I save data to plist like this:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    if (nil == data) {
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    }
    else {
        [data retain];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [array setObject:label1.text forKey:@"Test1"];
    [array setObject:label2.text forKey:@"Test2"];
    [array setObject:label3.text forKey:@"Test3"];
    [array setObject:label4.text forKey:@"Test4"];

    NSLog(@"%@", array);
    [data addObject:array];
    [array release];

    [data writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
    [data release];
}
```

NSLog:

```
2012-07-01 18:52:19.566 testapp[22651:707] {
    Test1 = 40;
    Test2 = 102;
    Test3 = 153;
    Test4 = 255;
}
```

How can I load saved data to `uitableview`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read it, do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

You should then be able to read the values for all the keys like this:

```
NSString *myValue = [plistDict objectForKey:@"someKey"];
```

**edit:**

After rereading your code it seems like you might be doing something you don't want to do. Your current plist structure is a top level array that adds a dictionary to itself every time you invoke "save". Is this what you're trying to do? If so, what represents a cell in your table, an index in the array?

If so, then you want to do

```
// top level array
NSMutableDictionary* plistArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

// individual dictionary at one array index (such as indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath)
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [plistArray objectAtIndex:yourIndex];
```

In any case, the object you have named "array" is actually a dictionary so you should rename it (or change it to be an array if that's what you want).

Comment: My point is to save new data as new dictionary every time I invoke "save" rather than replace each time the old one. I don't have any table yet, because I do not know how it should look like.